# Updating currently-read row using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I need to update a column in a large table (over 30 million rows) that has no primary key.  A table row has a unique email address column.  The update involves generating a value that must occur in C# and appending it to a column value.  So the row must be read, the column value updated, and written back out.

I was hoping there was a concept of cursoring in ADO.NET but I do not see this.  I can read the rows quickly enough, but the update call, using a WHERE clause for the email address, takes forever.  After researching this most answers seem to be "put in a primary key!" but that is not an option here.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Why is adding a primary key not an option??? Do you at least have a clustered index? And yes if you are updating 30 million rows by calling an update for each and every row this is going to take forever.

Comment: I do not own this table, therefore I cannot add a primary key.

Comment: Does it have a clustered index?

Comment: No indexes of any kind.

Comment: Is this school assignment, because table without primary key and indexes ... Also if you can select fast by email this indicates that there is an index by email column.

Comment: So you have a heap with 30 million rows and performance is a problem? You will never be able to make this any faster with a 30 million row heap. Every single query has to scan the column every single time it runs. And you state the values must come from c#? You are going to be forced to do this update row by agonizing row and each one is going to take a considerable amount of time because your table is not really a table, it is just a collection of information.

Comment: Yes, it's not usual.  If it were a school assignment the conditions would be more ideal.  The table is essentially a repository for a data dump.  It's flat.

Comment: You can read more about heaps (tables with no clustered index) here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213609.aspx

Comment: I'm not 'selecting fast by email' the read operation iterates through the table sequentially.

Comment: Well looping through 30 million rows is painful enough. But when you add an update query for each iteration it is going to suck the wind out of your server. This is 30 million individual update statements and each update has to scan every row to see if that row matches the where clause in your update. Remember you don't have a unique index on the table so the update looks at every single row because it doesn't know that the values are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 30mil rows [heap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213609.aspx), there's not many options. Without any index you can do basically nothing to speed it up.

Only solution is to [check a fragmentation](http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2013/03/dealing-with-fragmented-heap.html) of a heap. You should add a clustered index to alleviate the table fragmentation, then drop it immediately. But if you cannot affect that table in any way, it could be faster to move all the data into a new table :-)

Comment: Sometimes things are just not possible, and I informed the owners of this table of that and they are going to add an index.